# How to iterate over and calculate over a array of objects?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

So to keep it simple, the below is my requirement that I am trying to achieve in my LWC component:

Input :

```
[{name: "John", answer: "cloud"}, {name:"Jenny", answer:"Earth"},{name:"Jake", answer: "cloud"}]
```

If 2 or more objects have the same answer in the array, then create a new array of objects like so:

Output:

```
[{name:"John", points:1}, {name:"Jenny", points:0}, {name:"Jake", points:1}]
```

Basically, if anyone answers with the same words as anyone else, then its a +1 point for them. If they match with 2 people, then its +2 points etc...

Any help appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So we can re-phrase it to the following: for each object in the array, calculate the number of repeated answers and convert that into the point.

You can split this into 2 actions: calculate the number of occurrence for the answer,  map points based on the answer:

```
let input = [{name: "John", answer: "cloud"}, {name:"Jenny", answer:"Earth"},{name:"Jake", answer: "cloud"}];

let occurrence = input.reduce((prev, value) => ({
   ...prev,
   [value.answer]: (prev[value.answer] || 0) + 1
}), {});

let points = input.map((element) => ({...element, points: occurrence[element.answer] - 1}));
console.dir(points);
```

and output for `points` is:

```
[
   {
      "name":"John",
      "answer":"cloud",
      "points":1
   },
   {
      "name":"Jenny",
      "answer":"Earth",
      "points":0
   },
   {
      "name":"Jake",
      "answer":"cloud",
      "points":1
   }
]
```

Comment: Thanks @Oleksandr Berehovsky. Your solution seems very elegant. To the point where I do not completely understand the logic in the reduce function. Could you explain what exactly its doing? Also, if I call the same function again, it needs to not have duplicate "names" in the points array. How to achieve that?

Comment: @LoveBomber777 reduce is a kind of cumulative function, allowing to iterate elements of an array with an access to the cumulative result and current value. to read more [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?retiredLocale=uk)

Comment: I do understand how the reduce function works, but could you please tell me what is this doing - "[value.answer]: (prev[value.answer] || 0) + 1" and then in the map function you are substracting it? Are you comparing the answers and then adding 1? Apologies for not getting it.

Answer (score 1):

offcourse Oleksandr solution is pretty but i have simplified for you below.
In my solution, i have tried to get the total occurrences and store in map

```
let input = [{name: "John", answer: "cloud"}, {name:"Jenny", answer:"Earth"},{name:"Jake", answer: "cloud"}];
let occurrences = input.reduce((occurrenceAccumulator, obj) => {
    if(occurrenceAccumulator.get(obj.answer) === undefined){
      occurrenceAccumulator.set(obj.answer, 1);
    } else {
      occurrenceAccumulator.set(obj.answer, occurrenceAccumulator.get(obj.answer) + 1);
    }
      return occurrenceAccumulator;
    }, new Map());

   console.log(occurences);
   let points = input.map((element) => ({...element, points: occurences.get(obj.answer) - 1}));
   console.log(points);
```